# How to get JavaScript stack trace from C++ call

Tags: javascript, c++

I have written a C++ module which I am calling from JavaScript.  In the C++ module is it possible to get the stack trace that identifies the following from the JavaScript call:

1. JavaScript file name
2. Function name (if call I made from a function)
3. Line number of call in file.

I know I can make calls from JavaScript before the call to identify the above information.  I am exploring if it is possible to achieve the same in the C++ function when it is called.

Comment: If `boost` is an option then you could have a look at [`boost.stacktrace`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html).  Otherwise you might have to wait for [`c++23`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace).

Comment: This would give a C++ stack trace, which I can do in C++ without boost, what I'm after is the JavaScript stack trace.

Comment: Hello @SPlatten, would you mind to correct your question to "How to get a JavaScript stac trace, while calling from C++?" or similar? Background: I have got the message "Suggested edit queue is full". Stackoverflow - you know?

Comment: @Jörg'Wuwei'Brüggmann, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the update:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#script-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by working with V8 directly. You'll lose the ABI stability offered by Node-API though.

Include v8.h and you can do this in one of your exposed functions:

```
    const size_t frameLimit = 100;
    auto isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    auto st = v8::StackTrace::CurrentStackTrace(isolate, frameLimit);
    size_t frameCount = st->GetFrameCount();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
        auto stackFrame = st->GetFrame(isolate, i);
        auto vScriptName = stackFrame->GetScriptName();
        auto vFunctionName = stackFrame->GetFunctionName();
        string functionName;
        string scriptName;
        auto lineNumber = stackFrame->GetLineNumber();
        auto column = stackFrame->GetColumn();

        if (!vFunctionName.IsEmpty()) {
            functionName = *v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, vFunctionName);
        }

        if (!vScriptName.IsEmpty()) {
            scriptName = *v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, vScriptName);
        }

        cout << "at: " << functionName << ":" << scriptName << ":" << lineNumber << ":" << column << endl;
    }
```

This creates a stacktrace object and iterates through the stackframes, retrieving the script name, function name, line number and column.

Comment: [Edit] My C module is not running with Node or the Node-API.  It is a stand along C++ application I've developed with Qt.  I don't have the v8.h header.

Comment: how do you call the C++ module then?

Comment: Its not a module, the C++ application is the engine developed using Qt, it allows JavaScript to be run and I have exposed parts of my engine to JavaScript so it can make calls to C++ routines.